# TYPO3: getting relative URLS with "/" in the beginning

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x

There is an extension in my TYPO3 website that uses the following line of Typoscript:

```
EXT:ts_example/social_bookmarks-min.js
```

This translates to

```
typo3conf/ext/ts_example/social_bookmarks-min.js?1416308825
```

If I use absolute URLs in my website, this is not a problem, but if I intend to use relative URLs, this won't work, as it won't replace the entire pathname of the base URL, since it does not start with "/".

In short, I wish that it would output this instead:

```
/typo3conf/ext/ts_example/social_bookmarks-min.js?1416308825
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main TypoScript use:

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

and DON't use `config.baseURL` at the same time!